# Map is auto sorted after submitting to controller?

Tags: java, spring, sorting, spring-mvc, dictionary

Today I faced a weird issue like this.
First, I initialize a map that store data for select object in jsp.

```
Map<String, String> bankIds = ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder() // Dummy data
                                          .put("", "")
                                          .put("JobStart", "Job Start Bank")
                                          .put("JobEnd", "Job End Bank")
                                          .put("CspMod", "Bank For Completed CSP Builds. Stock For Second Level Build")
                                          .put("TEMPBANK", "TEMPBANK")
                                          .build();
```

And in jsp, I add some hidden fields for storing this map without re-getting it from DB.

```
<div id="hiddenAttributes" hidden="hidden">
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${lotSearchForm.bankIds}">
    <form:input path="bankIds[${entry.key}]" />
</c:forEach>
```

But after submitting to server, the map is already sorted by key. Now the order is:

```
{CspMod=Bank For Completed CSP Builds. Stock For Second Level Build, JobEnd=Job End Bank, JobStart=Job Start Bank, TEMPBANK=TEMPBANK, =}
```

And the result is the order of options in select object is changed.

So here are my questions:
 1. Why the map is sorted after submitting to server? I used LinkedHashMap but the result is still the same.
2. Is there any way to prevent auto sort in map like my issue?
 3. Is there any solution for my design? The session is prohibited in my project.

Thanks

**EDIT**
For easy understand, here is my context:
First I have a map like this.

```
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> bankIds = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    bankIds.put("", "");
    bankIds.put("JobStart", "Job Start Bank");
    bankIds.put("JobEnd", "Job End Bank");
    bankIds.put("CspMod", "Bank For Completed CSP Builds. Stock For Second Level Build");
    bankIds.put("TEMPBANK", "TEMPBANK");
```

So, the order of this map is "" --> JobStart --> JobEnd --> CspMod --> TEMPBANK
This is the right order.

I use this map as the options of a  in jsp like this.

```
<form:select path="bankId" items="${lotSearchForm.bankIds}"/>
```

In the output html, the order of options is the same with order of above map.
To prevent re-getting data from DB (data of map), I also add hidden attributes of map.

```
<div id="hiddenAttributes" hidden="hidden">
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${lotSearchForm.bankIds}">
    <form:input path="bankIds[${entry.key}]" />
</c:forEach>
</div>
```

Till now, the order is correct. The output html is in right order

```
<div id="hiddenAttributes" hidden="hidden">
    <input type="text" name="bankIds[]" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="bankIds[JobStart]" value="Job Start Bank" />
    <input type="text" name="bankIds[JobEnd]" value="Job End Bank" />
    <input type="text" name="bankIds[CspMod]" value="Bank For Completed CSP Builds. Stock For Second Level Build" />
    <input type="text" name="bankIds[TEMPBANK]" value="TEMPBANK" />
</div>
```

But when I execute the search action, the data map that I received from controller is not in right order.
The map IS SORTED after SUBMITTING to controller. Now, the order of map is:
CspMod --> JobEnd --> JobStart --> TEMPBANK --> ""

--> What I want is the received map has the same order with initialize map.
Clear?

Comment: Have you try to send to controllers an aditional list?

Comment: With a list, that's ok. But the issue is in map, not list and i'm not intent on using two list to replace a map.

Answer (score 0):

A map has no defined sort order unless you use a specialised implementation which adds this on top e.g. you use a SortedSet / TreeSet / LinkedHashMap instead.

Guavas ImmutableSet uses a hash based ordering - which is random by design.

Comment: As you see in my post, I just use ImmutableMap from Guava. And it does not matter to order. It's just from browser to server only. As I mentioned, I used LinkedHashMap but it does not change the result.

Comment: And I don't want to use list instead. Because I will need two list for one select object in jsp, right?

Comment: i am not sure where you expect things to be sorted - in the HTML output or when receiving a form post from the client as a response?

Comment: Hey, did you read my question? The map is auto sorted AFTER submitting to controller. That means the order of my map is changed when I re-get it from html, and that is my issue. Clear?

Comment: Can you show the controller code which receives the response? this does not seem to be related to your JSP code at all and can probably be reproduced with a standalone HTML page.